# How do I apply formatting to a cell based on comparison with another cell?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm working with Google's spreadsheets to keep a record of how many dragons of each breed/gender I have in a game I play. I have five columns:

```
A (Breed) | B (Male) | C (Male Goal) | D (Female) | E (Female Goal)
```

I want to highlight `B` with *green* if it is greater than or equal to `C`, *red* if it is less than `C`.

I want to highlight `D` with *green* if it is greater than or equal to `E`, *red* if it is less than `E`.

Obviously, I could use conditional formatting for each individual row to achieve this, but there's 116 rows so I was hoping there was a formula that would work for the entire column.

Answer (score 12):

Here is what you can do:

1. RightClick `B2` → select *Conditional formatting* → select *Custom Formula is* (from the List)
2. Enter the following formula in the textbox: 
   `=b2>=c2`
3. Check the *Background Color* and select green color
4. Click on *Add another rule*
5. Select *Custom Formula is* (from the List)
6. Enter the following formula in the textbox: 
    `=b2<c2`
7. Check the *Background Color* and select red color
8. Click on *Save Rules*
9. Highlight `B2` and click on *Paint Format* option on the tool bar.
10. Now click on cell  `B3` and drag until cell - `B117` (this should apply the conditional formatting on cell ranging from `B3`-`B117`)

And for your second condition (i.e., to highlight `D` with green if it is greater than or equal to `E`, red if it is less than `E`) - simply repeat the above steps by interchanging `D2` for `B2` and `E2` for `C2`.

Answer (score 3):

I think @Vembu's solution works but might be simplified in two ways:

1. Apply one of the colours as normal fill to both columns (or the required range for those columns). Then just use one CF rule (to overwrite that 'standard' formatting, when appropriate). All relevant cells in B and D are either one colour or the other, for which one CF rule is sufficient.
2. Copy the rule from one column to the other(B to D) with Paste special,  Paste format only. (The rule is the same for Male and Female, just shifted across two columns). This can however be achieved more easily by selection of the applicable Range, which may avoid copying other formatting where that is not to be replicated.

[image: WA69214 example]

So: select B2:B117 and D2:D117, fill red, Format, Conditional Formatting, Custom formula is `=B2>=C2` select Background Colour Green and Range: (which should already be selected as such) `B2:B117,D2:D117` (or to suit).

Answer (score 1):

Google Sheets has updated and now it looks like this `if you want conditionally format with red background if sum in two cells is different in 3rd cell`:
[image: Google Sheets conditional format rules with single color and custom formula]