# How to apply conditional formatting only if cell has X value? [google sheet]

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-filter

I have a sheet with statistical data to which I had applied color scale conditional formatting. Some rows I set to have green for highest and red for lowest number in row and other rows the other way around because I lower score would be better than lower.

But when applying a filter to the sheet and changing the order, I noticed that the conditional formatting got messed up and rows that I had set to have the highest number green had become red and visa versa.

**Is it possible to solve this with a conditional formatting that is only applied when cell in another column has a certain value?**

for example:

If the cell in column C in the same row has value "metric A" then apply color scale green to lowest en red to highest number.

and

if the cell in column C in the same row has value "metric B" then apply color scale red to lowest and green to highest number.

**or is there a better way, or some basic google sheet conditional formatting rule that applies when using filters that I am not aware of?**

Comment: Does [this](/questions/16745/how-can-i-set-conditional-formatting-on-a-particular-cell-that-depends-on-anothe) or [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/69214/how-do-i-apply-formatting-to-a-cell-based-on-comparison-with-another-cell) help?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, **color scale** conditional formatting can't be used based on another cell condition. This can be done only in **single color** conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply Conditional formatting based on a Formula that evaluates to TRUE or FALSE.
This is quite versatile, but it does not allow for using such formula as a condition for applying the color scale based on that.

One option is to define another conditional rule that reformats the target cells, based on the opposite criterion (negated formula).